# How to select distinct values on 2 columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have a `table` with col A and **col B**. **Col A** and **Col B** can have repetitive values.
I want to select distinct values from **Col A** and **Col B** individually and populate them in 1 column as unique values. How do I do that?

Example

```
col_a | col_b
------+------
 1    | 3 
 2    | 4 
 3    | 5 
 4    | 7 
 5    | 8  
 6    |
```

I want to `extract` the total unique values in a table that says `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`. How do I do that?

Comment: Should the result include or exclude the null value? (The col_b value from the row where col_a = 6.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a UNION to combine two results with each column. A `UNION` will remove  duplicates automatically:

```
select col_a as value
from the_table
union
select col_b 
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is to use a union:

```
SELECT DISTINCT val
FROM
(
    SELECT A AS val FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B FROM yourTable
) t;
```

### Demo

Comment: If you would use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` you wouldn't need the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @S-Man You're right, but [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) already beat me to this better answer.